# How to insert specific image (from URL) on each page of in the Word document in the header

Tags: vba, ms-word

We need to display on each page of the Word document in the footer (or title) some image that corresponds to the number of the current page. Each image is downloaded by its own Internet link corresponding to the page number, e.g. http://example.com/page1.png, http://example.com/page2.png,..etc.
Is it possible to do this by means of Word or VBA? I did a lot of experiments, but unsuccessfully. Inserted on the first page image in unchanged view displayed on the other page headers.

```
Sub Test1()
'get page number
Dim rng As Word.Range
Dim fld As Word.Field

Set rng = Selection.Range
Set fld = rng.Fields.Add(rng, wdFieldPage)

ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Fields.Add Range:=ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range, Type:=wdFieldIncludePicture, Text:="http://example.com/page" + CStr(fld.Result)


fld.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: A **Header** or **Footer** displays on *every page* of a Section - the described behavior is doing what Word was designed to do. If every page needs to be different, then position these things at the bottom of each page and not in the header/footer.

Comment: Note that in order to supplement a question with images you should use the Stack Overflow editing tool, not provide links to outside files. People don't like to follow such links, and especially not have to log-in to some kind of service. You might want to review the information about posting on the site in the [help].